# how do I make sublime recognize a javascript library

Tags: javascript, sublimetext

I have Javascript libraries downloaded in different folders, how do I set the path for them to be picked up by sublime. (and hopefully also show autocomplete for them)

I believe the right way to get the library into a js file is this:

`var highcharts = require('highcharts');`

Neither does it pick up the library nor does it do any autocomplete.

I've had problems with Emmet (same as the one mentioned here https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues/129) so I have the following plugins installed:

- Javascript Next
- Javascript Completions
- SublimeCodeintel
- SublimeLinter-jshint

For the autocompletions I've already asked a question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079474/get-autocomplete-for-new-javascript-libraties-in-sublime) but the problem I want to get solved here is getting the library recognized and thereby suggest autocomplete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [All Autocomplete](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/All%20Autocomplete) plugin, it finds matches in all open files of the current window.